# How can i force trigger commit the transaction

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have a oracle trigger where i call a procedure that uses UTL_HTTP method, and i have to ignore any error and commit the transaction. How can I do that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_MYTRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON MYTAB
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  MY_STATUS NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

  MY_PROCEDURE(PARAMS..., MY_STATUS); -- THIS IS OPTIONAL

  :NEW.MY_STATUS := MY_STATUS ;

END
```

Comment: Please be aware that a call to something UTL_HTTP or anything that is not transactional by nature may be called *multiple* times even for an update of a *single* row.  You cannot assume one row = one call within a trigger. It may be better to use dbms_job.submit to request a call to the UTL_HTTP, since the job will then be created and/or rolled back along with the parent transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger can not commit (or rollback) a transaction. If you need to ignore any error of the called procedure, you need to add an [exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-0502DC1A-F0A5-4180-A912-6A5CDC855F56):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_MYTRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON MYTAB
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  MY_STATUS NUMBER(10);
BEGIN

  begin 
     MY_PROCEDURE(PARAMS..., MY_STATUS); -- THIS IS OPTIONAL
  exception 
    when others then 
      my_status := -42; -- signal an error through the status value
  end;

  :NEW.MY_STATUS := MY_STATUS;
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you, is exactly this solution that i was looking. begin into begim